# Retro effects in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, glsl

I would like to know how to achieve the retro effects in libgdx like this game
[Paradox game](https://youtube.com/watch?v=_fPmN5ho7ho) what shader can I use?

Comment: Normally in a question you should show what you have tried so far... Regarding retro graphics, simply use _blocky_ pixels, that's normally enough to achieve a reto look.

Comment: Looking at the video he posted, @munyul, I think he's looking for what I'd call "CRT-like effects" or other post-processing/shaders. I agree though, Harry should really describe what he's found and tried so far, otherwise his question seems off-topic.

Comment: OK I found this https://dbeef.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/easy-shaders-via-libgdx-contribs-postprocessing/ I'll try to implement it.

Comment: Linked video is unavailable.